# Notify backend that container has been deployed

Tags: docker

I want to create containers which start small webservices. Developers of our team should then upload small images which contain different services. A main backend system then uses these services.

My problem is: When a developer uploads a new service, how does the backend service know there is a new service it can use? Beforehand, when service X should be used and there was no service for that functionality, it returned just a simple message. When there is a service uploaded to do X, the main backend should use that service. But how does it know it is there and should be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some notification to your small web service. But what do you do when the service will be down unexpectedly or network will be down at the short time? You need add some logic to clients for refreshing connection.

And docker [recommends](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) to use this way.

> The problem of waiting for a database (for example) to be ready is
>   really just a subset of a much larger problem of distributed systems.
>   In production, your database could become unavailable or move hosts at
>   any time. Your application needs to be resilient to these types of
>   failures.
>
> To handle this, your application should attempt to re-establish a
>   connection to the database after a failure. If the application retries
>   the connection, it should eventually be able to connect to the
>   database.
>
> The best solution is to perform this check in your application code,
>   both at startup and whenever a connection is lost for any reason.